# To bring Title from output of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query

```
select distinct Task_Date as LastSevendate from [TimeSheet]
where Task_Date between DateAdd(DD,-9,GETDATE()-1 ) and GETDATE()-1
```

OUTPUT will be

```
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000
2016-10-06 00:00:00.000
2016-10-07 00:00:00.000
2016-10-10 00:00:00.000
2016-10-11 00:00:00.000
2016-10-12 00:00:00.000
2016-10-13 00:00:00.000
```

I need to print like this dynamically in SQL.Please help me

```
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000  2016-10-06 00:00:00.000 2016-10-07 00:00:00.000 2016-10-10 00:00:00.000 2016-10-11 00:00:00.000 2016-10-12 00:00:00.000 2016-10-13 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Search for **Dynamic Pivot in Sql Server**

Comment: What do you mean by print?  What are you using as your front end?  I suggest `Write` and not `WriteLine`.

Comment: Is your desired output one field? Or is it meant to be separated into columns? If it's just one field, you'll want to use a `FOR XML`. Otherwise, as prdp mentioned, you may want to investigate Dynamic Pivot queries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want string concatenation.  One method is:

```
select stuff( (select distinct ' ' + convert(varchar(255), Task_Date, 121) 
               from [TimeSheet]
               where Task_Date between DateAdd(day, -9, GETDATE() - 1 ) and GETDATE() - 1
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using a variable:

```
declare @column varchar(max) = ''
Select @column = @column + ' ' + Task_Date from timesheet
select @column
```

OUPUT:

```
 2016-10-05 00:00:00.000 2016-10-06 00:00:00.000 2016-10-07 00:00:00.000 2016-10-10 00:00:00.000 2016-10-11 00:00:00.000 2016-10-12 00:00:00.000 2016-10-13 00:00:00.000
```